# How to send bulk email using javascript by azure ACS

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to send bulk email using javascript by Azure Communication Services

```js
const { EmailClient } = require("@azure/communication-email");

const connectionString = "endpoint=https://callandsms.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const client = new EmailClient(connectionString);
const sender = "support@xxxxx.azurecomm.net";
const emailContent = {
  subject: "Send email quick start test- JS sample",
  plainText: "Test Email from JS Send Email Sample Application\n\n This email is part of testing of email communication service. \\n Best wishes",
  html: "<html><head><title>ACS Email as a Service</title></head><body><h1>ACS Email as a Service - Html body</h1><h2>This email is part of testing of email communication service</h2></body></html>",
};
const toRecipients = {
  to: [
    { email: "xxxxx@yahoo.com", displayName: "xxx" },
    { email: "xxxxx@gmail.com", displayName: "xxx" },
  ],
};

async function main() {
  try {
    const emailMessage = {
      sender: sender,
      content: emailContent,
      recipients: toRecipients,
    };

    const sendResult = await client.send(emailMessage);

    if (sendResult && sendResult.messageId) {
      // check mail status, wait for 5 seconds, check for 60 seconds.
      const messageId = sendResult.messageId;
      if (messageId === null) {
        console.log("Message Id not found.");
        return;
      }

      console.log("Send email success, MessageId :", messageId);

      let counter = 0;
      const statusInterval = setInterval(async function () {
        counter++;
        try {
          const response = await client.getSendStatus(messageId);
          if (response) {
            console.log(`Email status for {${messageId}} : [${response.status}]`);
            if (response.status.toLowerCase() !== "queued" || counter > 12) {
              clearInterval(statusInterval);
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Error in checking send mail status: ",e);
        }
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      console.error("Something went wrong when trying to send this email: ", sendResult);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("################### Exception occoured while sending email #####################", e);
  }
}

main();
const { EmailClient } = require("@azure/communication-email");

const connectionString = "endpoint=https://callandsms.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const client = new EmailClient(connectionString);
const sender = "support@xxxxx.azurecomm.net";
const emailContent = {
  subject: "Send email quick start test- JS sample",
  plainText: "Test Email from JS Send Email Sample Application\n\n This email is part of testing of email communication service. \\n Best wishes",
  html: "<html><head><title>ACS Email as a Service</title></head><body><h1>ACS Email as a Service - Html body</h1><h2>This email is part of testing of email communication service</h2></body></html>",
};
const toRecipients = {
  to: [
    { email: "xxxxx@yahoo.com", displayName: "xxx" },
    { email: "xxxxx@gmail.com", displayName: "xxx" },
  ],
};

async function main() {
  try {
    const emailMessage = {
      sender: sender,
      content: emailContent,
      recipients: toRecipients,
    };

    const sendResult = await client.send(emailMessage);

    if (sendResult && sendResult.messageId) {
      // check mail status, wait for 5 seconds, check for 60 seconds.
      const messageId = sendResult.messageId;
      if (messageId === null) {
        console.log("Message Id not found.");
        return;
      }

      console.log("Send email success, MessageId :", messageId);

      let counter = 0;
      const statusInterval = setInterval(async function () {
        counter++;
        try {
          const response = await client.getSendStatus(messageId);
          if (response) {
            console.log(`Email status for {${messageId}} : [${response.status}]`);
            if (response.status.toLowerCase() !== "queued" || counter > 12) {
              clearInterval(statusInterval);
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Error in checking send mail status: ",e);
        }
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      console.error("Something went wrong when trying to send this email: ", sendResult);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("################### Exception occoured while sending email #####################", e);
  }
}

main();
```

I want to send emails to many users without the recipients seeing who I'm sending

[image]

Is there a solution to send mail individually and import emails from a text or excel file?
I tried a lot and I couldn't on my own

Please help and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may structure to send an email for each recipient and this way it will be hidden from the rest.

```js
let emailMessage = {sender: sender, content: emailContent};

for(let i = 0; i< toRecipients.to.length; i++) {
  emailMessage.recipients = {to: toRecipients.to[i] }; // single email
  const sendResult = await client.send(emailMessage);
}
```

Comment: const send result = await client.send(emailMessage);
         ^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Comment: well, that was a typo, a generic js error. I fixed it now, but you still have to populate it accordingly with the rest of the code.